# Disable stop the object when it is hit on the right position

Tags: actionscript-3

I want to be a drag and drop game.When I will to start drag my object be a small size to a drop position.It is performed correctly.But when drag object is touched hit point, it could not stop drag. Can I stop drag?Here is my code.....

```
 drag_6.buttonMode = true;
 drag_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe6);
 drag_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe6);


 var back_6X:Number = back_6.x;
 var back_6Y:Number = back_6.y;

 var hit_6X:Number = hit_6.x;
 var hit_6Y:Number = hit_6.y;

 var drop_6H:Number = drop_6.height;
 var drop_6W:Number = drop_6.width

 function dragMe6(event:MouseEvent)
 {
   drag_6.startDrag();

   drag_6.height=drop_6H;   
   drag_6.width=drop_6W;
   setChildIndex(drag_6, this.numChildren-1);
 }

 function dropMe6(event:MouseEvent)
 {
     drag_6.stopDrag();


     if (drag_6.hitTestObject(drop_6))
     {
        TweenMax.to(drag_6, 0.5, {x:hit_6X, y:hit_6Y,        ease:Cubic.easeOut});
        drag_6.mouseEnabled = false;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        drag_6.alpha = 0 ;
        hit_6.alpha = 1;
        drag_6.buttonMode = false;

     }
     else 
     {
       TweenMax.to(drag_6, 0.5, {x:back_6X, y:back_6Y, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
       SoundMixer.stopAll();
     }


  }
```

Comment: Offtopic but definitely +1 for your will to be a drag and drop game ;)

Comment: please give me answer.....it is very important for me.....  is it possible or not.....?

Comment: check the dropMe6 function is triggering or not by using trace inside the function. let me know the result

Comment: it will be perfectly done dragMe6 function.but dropMe6 is not working.That why I can not stop dragging.Please give me a solution......

Answer (score 0):

The reason is the mouseup event is not firing at all. The best a simple way to add event listeners to stage. `

```
drag_6.buttonMode = true;
 drag_6.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, dragMe6);

 var back_6X:Number = back_6.x;
 var back_6Y:Number = back_6.y;

 var hit_6X:Number = hit_6.x;
 var hit_6Y:Number = hit_6.y;

 var drop_6H:Number = drop_6.height;
 var drop_6W:Number = drop_6.width

 function dragMe6(event:MouseEvent)
 {
   stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe6);
   drag_6.startDrag();

   drag_6.height=drop_6H;   
   drag_6.width=drop_6W;
   setChildIndex(drag_6, this.numChildren-1);
 }

 function dropMe6(event:MouseEvent)
 {
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, dropMe6);
     drag_6.stopDrag();


     if (drag_6.hitTestObject(drop_6))
     {
        TweenMax.to(drag_6, 0.5, {x:hit_6X, y:hit_6Y,        ease:Cubic.easeOut});
        drag_6.mouseEnabled = false;
        SoundMixer.stopAll();
        drag_6.alpha = 0 ;
        hit_6.alpha = 1;
        drag_6.buttonMode = false;

     }
     else 
     {
       TweenMax.to(drag_6, 0.5, {x:back_6X, y:back_6Y, ease:Bounce.easeOut});
       SoundMixer.stopAll();
     }


  }
```

Make sure the global stage object is accessible.

Comment: did it work?  then make it answer so that someone else could use it.